# Xero GET Response Truncated by TLS Close Notify

Tags: xero-api, tls1.3

We are using a Custom Connector to pull Bills data from the API's 2.0 Invoice endpoint.
This has been in production for 18 months with no issues.

Over the last four weeks, there has been an increasing occurrence of the cURL GET request failing.
When it fails, the cURL trace reports that the data transfer was closed by a TLS request, mid stream.

partial cURL trace:

> Info: TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS alert, close notify (256):
>
> Recv SSL data, 2 bytes (0x2)
>
> 0000: 01 00                                           ..
>
> Info: transfer closed with 9467 bytes remaining to read
>
> Info: Closing connection 0
>
> Info: TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS header, Supplemental data (23):
>
> Send SSL data, 5 bytes (0x5)
>
> 0000: 17 03 03 00 13                                  .....
>
> Send SSL data, 1 bytes (0x1)
>
> 0000: 15                                              .
>
> Info: TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS alert, close notify (256):
>
> Send SSL data, 2 bytes (0x2)
>
> 0000: 01 00

The problems were first reported mid-June 2023, when the occasional request started to report a failure.
Subsequent requests may be successful, however over the last week only 1 out of 50 identical requests return the full payload.
We have tested the connection from multiple locations/environments, and have ruled out firewall/network connectivity issues.

The partial result returned (as per the cURL tracelog) is valid data - ie the JSON payload that we requested. It's just that it's truncated.

I'm keen to know if there have been recent performance issues for the Xero API, or other issues that others have discovered.